# $"...{}..." string literals in C#?

Tags: c#, string, format

I want to know why this code works correctly in C# (at least with Visual Studio 2015).
Where can I found information about string literals starting with $ in C#?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var name = "José";
        var age = 40;
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}, you have {age} years");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). Not sure it warrants an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's c# 6 Interpolated Strings, you can read more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)